# Android Studio: More than one Manifest

Tags: android-manifest, android-studio

I have been working on an Android project using Android studio.
All of a sudden, when I try to run the code, I got the below error

ADB not responding. You can wait more, or kill "adb" process manually and click 'Restart'     Errors from ADB: ddms: Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger

I closed the studio and on reopening it, the project structure is changed.
Now I see two Manifest files in the project. One in the 'Main' Folder and the other in the 'Debug' folder.

On trying to Run the project now, Studio shows errors saying resources, classes etc are not found. which point to the Manifest present in the 'Debug' folder.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong